# Uniqueness of the "asymptotic limit" of a sequence of gradient flow lines

Tags: differential-topology, morse-theory

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact smooth orientable riemannian manifold, and let $f: M \to \mathbb R$ be a [Morse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_function). All functions here are assumed to be smooth. We will be considering the integral curves and the flow $\varphi$ of the gradient vector field of $f$. That is
\begin{align}
& \varphi : \mathbb R \times M \to M, \\
& (t,x) \mapsto \varphi^t(x),
\end{align}
where $\varphi^t(x)$ is the solution of the ODE $\dot{u} = -\nabla(f(u))$ at time $t$, with initial value $x$. It is known that $\varphi^t(x)$ converges to critical points of $f$, as $t \to \pm \infty$. Given $p,q$ critical points of $f$, we set
\begin{align}
\mathcal M(p,q) := \{u: \mathbb R \to M : \dot{u} = -\nabla(f(u)), \lim_{t \to -\infty}u(t) = p, \lim_{t \to +\infty}u(t) = q \}.
\end{align}
Next, we assume that $f$ is [Morse-Smale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_homology#Formal_definition), so that $\mathcal M(p,q)$ is a smooth manifold (it essentially corresponds to the transverse intersection of a stable manifold with an unstable manifold). We consider on $\mathcal M(p,q)$ the $C^\infty_{loc}$-convergence, that is, the uniform convergence on every compacta of the derivatives of all orders. There is a free $\mathbb R$-action of $\mathcal M(p,q)$, defined by translation:
\begin{equation}
(\tau \cdot u)(s) = \varphi^\tau(u(s)) = u(s+\tau).
\end{equation}
The quotient $\widehat{\mathcal M}(p,q) = \mathcal M(p,q) / \mathbb R$ is the space of gradient flow lines from $p$ to $q$.

Finally, the problem.

> Let $(u_n)$ and $(u'_n)$ be two lifts of a sequence $(\hat{u}_n)$ in
>   $\widehat{\mathcal M}(p,q)$ (with respect to the usual projection to
>   the quotient). Suppose that \begin{align} & u_n
>  \stackrel{C^\infty_{loc}}\to v \\ & u'_n \stackrel{C^\infty_{loc}}\to
>  v', \end{align} where $v \in \mathcal{M}(p',q')$ and $v' \in \mathcal
>  M(p'',q'')$, for some critical points $p',p'', q',q''$ of $f$. Suppose
>   there exist numbers $s,s' \in \mathbb R$ such that
>   $f(v(s))=f(v'(s'))$. Prove that this implies $\hat{v} =\hat{v}'$.

(If necessary, assume also that $f$ is injective on critical points. I
 don't personally know whether it is important or not.)

Source: [www.math.uiuc.edu/~ekerman/mf-notes.ps](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~ekerman/mf-notes.ps), Exercise 1.5.8, page 26.